# JPA query for equality with @ManyToMany relationship

Tags: java, jpa

I have these classes:

```
public class Group {
    @ManyToMany 
    private Set<Person> members;
}
public class Person {
}
```

I use the following query (based on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22052537/jpa-query-with-manytomany-relationship-and-no-navigation?lq=1)) to find the groups which contains the specified members list:

```
select g from Groups g join g.members member where member in :members
```

(with :members being a Set)

Of course [Person1, Person2] matches [Person1, Person2] and also [Person1, Person2, Person3], ...

Now, I want to find the groups which match exactly the specified members list, i.e. [Person1, Person2] matches [Person1, Person2] but not [Person1, Person2, Person3].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should select all groups with the exact members list and no other members.

```
SELECT group1 FROM Groups group1
    JOIN group1.members member1
WHERE SIZE(:members) = (
        SELECT COUNT(member2) FROM Groups group2
            JOIN group2.members member2
        WHERE group2.id = group1.id)
    AND SIZE(:members) = (
        SELECT COUNT(member2) FROM Groups group2
            JOIN group.members member2
        WHERE group2.id = group1.id AND member2.id IN :members)
```

Basically, you want all groups with these conditions:

- The total number of members is equal to the size of the member collection you used as a parameter
- The total number of parameters in the group matching the ones in the member collection you used as a parameter are also equal to the size of the member collection

This should cover collection content equality. All the ones you are looking for are there and there aren't any more than that.

Also see: [Selecting an entity by collection set equality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22291993/selecting-an-entity-by-collection-set-equality) for an alternative, but similar technique.

Comment: it should be _JOIN group2.members_ instead of _JOIN group.members_ right ?

Comment: also, i have the following error _org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Unexpected expression ? found for collection function size_ when executing the query.

If i compute the size in java (and modifiy the query accordingly) it works fine.

Anyway thanks for your help, i'd have never thought of this way to solve the problem.

Comment: The first join clause "JOIN group1.members member1" should be removed: Since the relation is a many-to-many, there will be a join table with one row per group-member relation, and the same group can appear more than once. Hence, joining with member will get you not just the groups you want, but all group-member _relations_ for those groups, which could contain duplicate groups.

Comment: @MaD you can embed java code in queries like so: `where :#{#members.size()} = ...`.

Answer (score 0):

```
select g from Groups g inner join g.members member 
    where member.id in :members and not exists(
        select group.id 
            from Groups group inner join group.members xmember 
                where group.id = g.id and xmember.id in :excludeMembers)

members =  [Person1.id, Person2.id]
excludeMembers = [Person3.id]
```

Comment: I put up a different, more general, solution. This one will work if the full set of possible members is small and known. But it doesn't scale nicely when there are millions of possible members, for example.

Comment: @Chill Interesting. It doesn't need to have `excludeMembers`. I am not sure it will work :)